# In C printf print on stdout "\0" but shouldn't

Tags: c, string, char, printf

I use

```
./file.exe test.in | od -c
```

for print on the stdout even the hidden char printed by a `printf("someString")`, like `"\t"` or `"\n"`, the problem is that even `"\0"` gets printed, but shouldn't.

OUTPUT:

```
0000000   3   1  \t   2   7  \n  \0   S   S   S   S   E   E   E   E   E
0000020   N   N   W   W   N   N   E   E   E   E   E   S   S   S   S   S
0000040   S   S   S   E  \0  \0
0000046
```

i tried print i this way:

```
printf("%d",mov);
printf("\t");
printf("%d",wets);
printf("\n");
```

```
for (i = mov; i >= 0; i--) {
   printf("%c",movement[i]);
}`
```

in line 1-4 i tried to use a `printf()` for each char that need to be printed, instead using a just one printf

Comment: `%c` format will print any character, including `\0`.

Comment: Because \0 is a character, not “empty”

Comment: This is what print without "od -c":                                                                                       
31      27
SSSSEEEEENNWWNNEEEEESSSSSSSSE

Comment: The problem is that: "char movement[mov]" contains only char constant that can be 'S' || 'W' || 'E' || 'N'

Comment: @Visc0 *The problem is that: "char movement[mov]" contains only char constant that can be 'S' || 'W' || 'E' || 'N'*  Evidently `'\0'` `char` values too.

Answer (score 1):

The root of your problems seems to be exotic use of `for` loops. Whenever possible, avoid all loops which doesn't have the idiomatic form:

`for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)`

Other kind of loops are needlessly hard to read for everyone including yourself. Non-idiomatic loops start at a different index than 0 or end at a different condition than `<n`, or they use other iterator modifications than a simple `++`, or they count downwards etc. Sometimes there is no other way around it and then it's OK to use other forms, but don't do it needlessly because the code turns harder to read.

In your case you start at a counter and count downwards while `i>=0`. That is the logical equivalent of counting upwards from `i=0;` to `i<=n`, meaning one additional item. In most cases meaning an array out of bounds access bug.

To display something in the reverse order, you could write the loop like this instead:

```c
for(size_t i=0; i<mov; i++)
{
  printf("%c", movement[mov-i-1]); // -1 since arrays are 0-indexed
}
```